# How do text-editors recognize if the user wanted to type a number or the ascii value associated with it?

Tags: binary, ascii

According to my *current* understanding:-

1. All binary values are treated as **equal by the system**, and it is the task of the software (or the app) to interpret a binary value as text or image, etc. based on the **context in which the app expects the data to be.**
2. When a key is pressed by the user, **an event is fired** by the system and any running **application handles the event** and gets the value of the key pressed.

Now, take for example the user presses the tab key.

Binary Value of the horizontal tab (if I'm not wrong) -

```
00001001
```

When this binary value is converted into its decimal equivalent, we get **“9”** as the value.

Now my doubt[s] are:-

1. How does the text editor recognize **whether the value “9” or a horizontal tab is to be taken as the final value**? In other words,
2. How does the software know whether or not the **decimal value needs to be converted to its ASCII character equivalent**?
3. Whether the tab key or the digit 9 key was pressed?
4. How, or in what form, or with what details does the system fire an event for a keypress?

I would be glad if you could help me out (in simple terms, of course), and please do point out if I am mistaken at something.

Thank you!

Comment: Tab (ASCII 9) and 9 (ASCII 57) are totally different ASCII character codes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I think you were mission on 2 pretty important details.

Here they are:-

1. Different [`ASCII codes`](https://www.w3schools.com/charsets/ref_html_ascii.asp#:%7E:text=The%20ASCII%20Character%20Set&text=ASCII%20is%20a%207%2Dbit,are%20all%20based%20on%20ASCII.) are present for all the digits (0 through 9) as well, and that there is a different key code for the digit "9" and the decimal value "9", which, as @ggorlen pointed out, is the tab key.
2. Most of the applications always take in the `ASCII` (or any other type of character encoding) equivalent, instead of the decimal equivalent of a keypress's binary value.